# equations over (some) lie groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, linear-algebra

To be concrete, let $G=SL(n, \mathbb{C}),$ $\phi$ an automorphism of $G.$ Is there a characterization of those $x$ for which there exists a $y$ such that $x = y \phi(y)?$ In the special case, the automorphism group of $G$ is generated by inner automorphisms and 
$\psi(x) =  (x^{-1})^t.$ For inner $\phi,$ we are asking which $x$ satisfy the quadratic equation $x = y a y a^{-1}$ for a *fixed* a (if $a$ is allowed to vary, it is well-known that every element of a complex semi-simple lie group is a commutator, so that should presumably imply that every element has that form for *some* $a$ ). For $\psi,$ we want to characterize matrices of the form $y = x (x^{-1})^t$ (by dimension counting this is a proper subset; it is pretty clear that it contains the complex orthogonal group).

Comment: Why is the subset of matrices $y=x(x^{-1})^t$ proper?

Comment: It is proper for $n=2$, but not because of the dimension. The set has full dimension 3. It is just the whole $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ without some subvariety of co-dimension 1. 

Comment: Well, I was doing this in my head, and observed that at identity all of the symmetric directions are annihilated by the jacobian of $x \rightarrow x \psi(x).$ At a general point, the annihilation condition is that $v^t = x v x^t,$ and it is not clear that this has any nontrivial solutions (for traceless $v$), so this is not clear...

Comment: I do not understand the comment. The case $n=2$ is easy, and can be treated using any CAS. 

Comment: @Igor: To avoid confusion, the definition of `$\psi$` in the third lilne of the question should be corrected by removing the factor `$x$` on the left.

Comment: In fact, for $n=2$ the set of matrices of the form $x(x^{-1})^t$ is precisely the set of all matrices in $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ which are not unipotent (i.e. matrices with eigenvalues $\ne 1$). I wonder if that is true for all $n$.

Comment: Correction: the only unipotent matrix in that set is the identity. 

Comment: @Mark: that is possible (about the unipotents). The point of my remark is that if there is a single point where the Jacobian of the map $x \rightarrow x \psi(x)$ is nonsingular, then the image is Zariski-open in $G,$ as you are suggesting.

Comment: For every $n>2$ my conjecture is false. I am not even sure that not all matrices in $SL_n(\mathbb{C})$ of size $n>2$ are of that form. As I mentioned in my answer, it is enough to consider triangular matrices. 

Comment: I think Update 4 in my answer is very close to a complete description (certainly for $n=3$ and most probably for all $n$).  

Comment: You might be right. Can you show that all of the complex symplectic group is in the set? (since that certainly has the property that eigenvalues come in pairs...)

Comment: @Igor: Your original problem can be reduced to upper triangular matrices as I described in my answer. Triangular matrices satisfying your condition can be described, I am sure. The question about symplectic group cannot be reduced to triangular matrices, at least I do not know how. So I do not know the answer.  

Comment: @Mark: yes, I understand, the point is that if you state your conjecture that a matrix is "representable" iff its eigenvalues come in inverse pairs, in particular that means that the whole symplectic group is "representable". It might be that the best way to prove the symplectic statement is to prove your conjecture...

Comment: What I actually showed is that if $y$ is representable, then the characteristic polynomials of $y$ and $y^{-1}$ coincide (because $\chi(y)=\chi(x(x^{-1})^t)=\chi(x^{-1}x^t)=\chi(x^tx^{-1})=\chi(y^{-1})$. For unitary matrices the converse is not true. For non-unitary matrices - I do not know. 

Comment: $\chi(y)=\chi(y^{-1})$ means, of course, that if $n$ is even, the coefficients of $\chi(y)$ form a palindrom ($a_i=a_{n-i}$), and if $n$ is odd, they form a skew palindrom ($a_i=-a_{n-i}$). 

Comment: The last condition being exactly the condition to be a characteristic polynomial of a symplectic matrix...

 

Comment: Also, I think you mean "unipotent" when you say unitary.

Comment: Yes: it should be unipotent. 

Answer (score 5):

For every $x$ the equation $x=yaya^{-1}$ has a solution. Indeed, replace $ya$ by $z$. We get $x=z^2a^{-2}$ or $xa^2=z^2$. But in $SL_n(\mathbb{C})$ every element is a square, so $z$ can be found, hence $y=za^{-1}$ exists.

**Update 1.**  In order to see that every complex non-singular matrix is a square, it is enough to consider a Jordan block $J_n(a)$ ($a$'s on the diagonal, 1 on the next diagonal, the rest are 0). If we denote $b=\sqrt{a}$, then a square root of $J_n(a)$ is a triangular matrix, it has $b$ on the diagonal,
$2/b$ on the next diagonal, $-\frac{1}{8b^3}$ on the second diagonal, $\frac{1}{16b^5}$ on the third diagonal, etc. The number on the diagonal # $i$ is equal to $c_i/(b^{2i-1})$ where $c_i$ can be defined by induction, it does not depend on $a$. Also if you represent your matrix as $A=\exp(B)$ for some $B$, then the square root of $A$ is just $\exp(B/2)$. Note that we need $a\ne 0$, so this does not work for singular matrices.

**Update 2.**  About the equation $y=x(x^{-1})^t$. Note that this equation is stable under conjugation by complex orthogonal matrices (i.e. matrices $a$ with $a^t=a^{-1}$).Thus instead of $y$ we can consider  $aya^{-1}$ with $a$ orthogonal. Hence we can assume that $y$ is triangular. For $n=2$ this immediately gives:

** A triangular matrix $y\in SL_2(\mathbb{C})$ is of the form $x(x^{-1})^t$ if and only if either $y=1$ or the eigenvales of $y$ are not equal to 1. Thus $y$ is of that form iff either $y=1$ or $y$ is not unipotent.

**Update 3**  For $n=3$ the description is more complicated. For example, all uni-upper triangular representable matrices $A$ have the form
$$\left(\begin{array}{lll} 1 & ca &cb \\\ 0 & 1 & c\\\  0& 0 & 1\end{array}\right)$$
Hence if $A[3,2]=0$, $A$ must be equal to 1. On the other hand if $c\ne 0$, $A$ is arbitrary.

**Update 4.**  If $y=x(x^{-1})^t$, and $a$ is an eigenvalue of that matrix, then $1/a$ is also an eigenvalue. Indeed, $yv=av$ implies $y^tw=aw$ for some $w$ (since $y$ and $y^t$ have the same eigenvalues), $x^{-1}x^tw=aw$. Hence $x^tw=a xw$. Hence $1/aw=(x^{-1})^txw$, so $1/a$ is an eigenvalue of $(x^{-1})^tx$, hence an eigenvalue of $y$ (since matrices $pq$ and $qp$ have the same eigenvalues). This implies for $n=3$, a matrix $y$ of that form must have eigenvalue 1.

Comment: I might be more jet lagged than I thought, but it seems to me that substituting $y=za$ gives you $x=z a a z a a^{-1} = z a^2 z \neq z^2 a^{-2}.$ 

Comment: A misprint: you need to substitute $z=ya$ (I fixed that). Then $yaya^{-1}=zza^{-1}a^{-1}=z^2a^{-2}$.

Comment: Though since every invertible matrix is a square, as you say, my first question is equivalent to, for every $b,$ the solvability of $x = y b y.$

Comment: Ah, OK, I am too jet lagged to fix typos :)


Comment: That's very interesting: I did not see whether you checked whether all non-unipotent matrices are representable, or is that still a conjecture only...

Comment: No, in the case $n=3$, every matrix of the form $x(x^{-1})^t$ has one of the eigenvalues 1. For non-unipotent matrices, it looks like the only restriction. In general, I think that if $a$ is an eigenvalue of that matrix, then $1/a$ is also an eigenvalue, and that is the only restriction for non-unipotent matrices. It can be rigorously proved, I am sure. 